How to limit the stretching amount on a cloth rope, instead of allowing infinite elongation
I have the following scenario (see picture):

A rope is modelled as a group of vertex, with a skin and subdivision modifiers.
This rope is hanging from a top plane and it's configured as Cloth.
Its Upper end is hooked to an Empty, which is parented (Keeping transforms) to the top plane
Its lower end is hooked to another Empty, which is parented (Keeping transforms) to an active Rigid body, supported on top of another passive rigid body.
The active rigid body and its supporting passive rigid body are constrained by means of another Empty with a Hinge relationship.
As the Center of Gravity of the main object lies to the left of the Hinge axis, when playing the animation it starts falling (rotating around the hinge) while keeping the connection with the rope, which extends as much as it might be requested without any limitation.

I want to limit the amount of stretching that the rope could stand, so that it does not allow for a complete revolution, but it only falls a few degrees and holds the main object.
I tried playing with all Cloth parameters without any success. I also searched all previously asked questions but I'm unable to find a working solution.
Could anyone provide some guidance?
Thanks a lot in advance



After doing some more research, I just realized that Rigid Body and Cloth simulations do not interact too much, so I came up with a workaround which is to create an additional "General Spring constraint" in between the main object (active) and the top plane (passive), and activate all angular and linear axes. By means of this constraint, the amount of turn around the hinge gets constrained and it fakes a limited stretching on the cloth rope. Now it's a matter of playing with the spring settings so that it becomes more realistic.
